# How to add Okta access token by default to all axios request

Tags: vue.js, axios, okta

I have setup Okta with my vuejs application. To communicate with my api you need an access token with every axios reqeust. The axios config is setup as follows:

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $axios: AxiosInstance;
  }
}

// Set config defaults when creating the instance
const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:5293/api' : 'https://testsite.com/api',
    headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
  });
  
  // Alter defaults after instance has been created
  //instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;

export default api
```

This works great but in order to do the request I have to manually add the header:

```
      const oktaAuth = getCurrentInstance()?.appContext.app.config.globalProperties.$auth as OktaAuth
  const accessToken = oktaAuth.getAccessToken();
  const config = {
    headers:{
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
    }
  };

  function getAppointmentData() {
    //axios call
    api.get<appointmentList[]>('/calendar',config)
    .then((response) => {   
      dataAppointmentList.value = response.data;   
    })
    .catch(() => {
      dataAppointmentList.value = []; 
      console.log('API request failed');
    })
  }
```

It is not a huge pain to add the token each time but if there is a way to do this by default in the config file that would be great. I tried taking the getInstance() and doing in the config but the token comes back as null always so I am thinking its because its not reactive and the axios config file loads before even logging in.

Comment: What is not working with `api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = \`Bearer ${oktaAuth.getAccessToken()}\`` ?

Comment: Global defaults should work fine, but you have a typo here:  `instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN; `  
It should be:
`instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer' + AUTH_TOKEN;`

Comment: Could you post the final solution with the imports that I would need to use instance?

Comment: It's unknown how you use Okta in Vue. Is it a plugin?

Comment: @madflow used `instance` because that's what's in your commented out code, which probably came from [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/config_defaults).  replace `instance` with `api` since thats how you defined your "axios instance" as when you did `const api = axios.create(...)`

Comment: If I add the following to my okta config file : const oktaAuth = getCurrentInstance()?.appContext.app.config.globalProperties.$auth as OktaAuth
api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${oktaAuth.getAccessToken()}`;  seems to break my code. Is this not correct?

Comment: break how?  please include error messages.  it's not known how you're authenticating, so maybe `getAccessToken()` doesn't return anything since axios instance is created when the app first runs, and don't you need to do some initial work to create a token?  so you may want to edit the axios instance _after_ the token is created (wherever that happens).  to check, just console log what `getAccessToken()` gives you.  Is it correct?

Comment: Just throwing this out there: [axios interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) let you run some specific code before each request, which could be good place to create, verify and/or add token to request.

Comment: @yoduh yes thats my issue . getAccessToken() is null because the config is loaded when the spa starts up and initiates. I need a way to let the config or this header field to be reactive and update once the token populates.

Comment: So what would be the solution? Should I add a computed property somehow? I am struggling with this. I mean its not the worst thing to have to allways add getinstance to every component i use a query in but I figured there had to be an easier way.